# Question on the correlation between two dependant variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

I'm working on this question and it's stumping me.

Let Sn = X1 + ... + Xn (with n>=1) be a random walk with X1,...,Xn be iid RV's. E(Xk)=mu Var(Xk)=sigma^2.

Find the covariance of Sn and Sm

Can anyone help out? I am trying to use the equation

Cov[Sn, Sm] = E[SnSm] - E[Sn]E[Sm]

Comment: Duplicate of same question by same author at:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119717/

Answer (score 0):

Just use properties of [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) (including its value under independence assumption).

Say $n<m$.

$${\rm Cov} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n {\rm Var}(X_i),$$
$${\rm Cov} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, X_j\right) =  {\rm Var}(X_j),$$
if $j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $0$, if $j\in \{n+1,\ldots,m\}$.

$${\rm Cov} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{j=1}^m X_j\right) = {\rm Cov} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{j=1}^n X_i\right) + {\rm Cov} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \sum_{j=n+1}^m X_j\right) $$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^n {\rm Var}(X_i) + \sum_{j=n+1}^m{\rm Cov} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,  X_j\right)  $$
$$= \sum_{i=1}^n {\rm Var}(X_i) + 0 = \sum_{i=1}^n {\rm Var}(X_i).$$

So the answer is:
$${\rm Cov}(S_n, S_m)= \min(n,m)\cdot\sigma^2. $$